# How To Remove A Pipe Symbol From Menu Generated With PHP Loop And XML

Tags: php, xml, loops

Wondering if someone could assist me with this.

I am generating menu options for both an ELEVAT (elevated) and AUTHOR (authorised basic user) using a PHP loop which accesses an XML file set so that secure = 0 or 1 as follows:

```
<menuitem>
<itemname>Edit Event</itemname>
<itemfilename>editevent.php</itemfilename>
<itemfilepath>scripts</itemfilepath>
<secure>0</secure>
</menuitem>
<menuitem>
<itemname>Archive</itemname>
<itemfilename>eventsarchive.php</itemfilename>
<itemfilepath>scripts</itemfilepath>
<secure>1</secure>
</menuitem>
```

0 = authorised basic user and 1 = elevated user

Considering that I have so many menu links now I have 2 rows for the elevated user, I am trying to output to the browser so that the last menu item of the first row of page links does not print a pipe.

So far I have managed to get the basic user login to generate without a pipe after the last link however I cannot for the life of me figure out how to remove the | from the last link of the first row of links for the elevated user login.

Here is my PHP function:

```
function pagemenu($pageFile)
{
    # Open the DB connection
    $sql      = dbconnect();
    $linkPath = getlinkpath($pageFile);
    # The $pageFile value is the file name of the calling page
    # Set the path to the menu source file
    $xmlsrc = $linkPath . 'xml/menulist.xml';
    # Load the menu source file into a SimpleXML object
    if (!$menulist = simplexml_load_file($xmlsrc)) {
        # Print an error message if the source file does not load
        print 'Unable to load the XML source file';
    } # Process the menulist.xml file
    else {
        # Set a counter for the menu items
        $itemCount = 1;
        # Find the folder path of the calling page
        foreach ($menulist as $menu) {
            if ($menu->itemfilename == $pageFile) {
                $linkPath = $menu->itemfilepath;
            } else {
                $linkPath = '';
            }
        }
        # Scroll through all the menu items and build the menu
        print '<div class="menubar">' . PHP_EOL;
        foreach ($menulist as $menu) {
            # If the menu item is the current page don't display a link
            if ($menu->itemfilename == $pageFile) {
                # Don't print a pipe before the first menu item
                if ($itemCount != 1) {
                    print ' | ';
                }
                print $menu->itemname;
            } # Display a link for all the other menu items
            else {
                # Construct the link path to the menu item file
                # A link to the index file
                if ($menu->itemfilepath == 'root') {
                    $thisLink = '../' . $menu->itemfilename;
                } # A link to a file in the same folder
                elseif ($menu->itemfilepath == $linkPath) {
                    $thisLink = $menu->itemfilename;
                } elseif ($pageFile == 'index.php' and $menu->itemfilepath != $linkPath) {
                    $thisLink = $menu->itemfilepath . '/' . $menu->itemfilename;
                } # A link to a file in a different folder
                elseif ($menu->itemfilepath != $linkPath) {
                    $thisLink = '../' . $menu->itemfilepath . '/' . $menu->itemfilename;
                }
                # Create the connection to the mysql database and handle error if there is one
                $query    = mysqli_query(
                    $sql, "SELECT user_type_id FROM user_details WHERE user_id =     '$_SESSION[validUser]'"
                );
                $usertype = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
                # Don't print a pipe before the first menu item
                if ($usertype['user_type_id'] == "ELEVAT") {
                    if ($itemCount != 1) {
                        # Tried the following added to the above line without success
                        # && ($itemCount !=11))
                        print ' | ';
                    }
                } else {
                    if (($itemCount != 1) && ($itemCount != 5) && ($itemCount != 6) && ($itemCount != 7)
                        && ($itemCount != 8)
                        && ($itemCount != 9)
                        && ($itemCount != 10)
                        && ($itemCount != 11)
                        && ($itemCount != 12)
                        && ($itemCount != 13)
                        && ($itemCount != 14)
                        && ($itemCount != 15)
                        && ($itemCount != 16)
                        && ($itemCount != 17)
                    ) {
                        print ' | ';
                    }
                }
                # Display the menu item as a link
                if ($menu->secure == 1) {
                    if ($usertype['user_type_id'] == "ELEVAT") {
                        print '<a href="' . $thisLink . '">' . $menu->itemname . '</a>';
                    }
                } else {
                    print '<a href="' . $thisLink . '">' . $menu->itemname . '</a>';
                }
            }
            # Increment the menu item counter
            $itemCount++;
        }
    }
    print '</div>' . PHP_EOL;

    return;
    # Close the DB connection
    mysqli_close($sql);
}
```

Comment: "I read it square down the page." really? Trying to decipher nested if loops without indentation can cause brain damage.

Comment: When you want to make a list of things with a separator between them, put them in an array and then use `implode(' | ', $array)` to join them. Then you won't have an extra separator at the end.

Comment: your function is too long and does too many things at once. Divide it into multiple functions that are of small size and have a single job. Also do [command/query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command–query_separation). This might sound a bit technical at first, but it's easy to do and understand and will help you to divide and solve your problem *easily*.

Comment: @Digital Chris - Like I said I'm new to programming so to avoid the "brain damage" I better learn indentation quick smart - I'll try your suggestion but I don't think it will fix the issue at hand - thanks for the feedback anyways

Comment: Honestly, it looks like your commented out solution COULD work assuming the 11th item is the end of the first row. @Barmar's solution is better though, just make an array for each row and implode it as he stated.

Comment: @tokenloko_ I have indented the code exemplary. That's just one suggestion how it could be intended, indentation is best done your own so you get a feeling for processing in your routines.

Comment: Any decent programming editor should provide automatic indentation, you don't need to learn it.

Comment: Also your question is too broad and will likely get closed. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help how to improve your question. It contains too much code. You need to create an example that works out of the box (no database or files here, the database as some array values and the XML as string probably) and it must be reduced to the concrete programming problem you want to ask about. Do not post your live-code, but always create an isolated example from scratch just for the question containing only the bare minimum to demonstrate the isolated problem - and properly formatted.

Comment: Apologies all - it's hard to know "how" to ask the question when you are new to the game - I don't know what to broad means as I thought the more info I provided the easier it may be for someone to assist - any tips? Freeby code editor with auto indentation + assist with the question?

Comment: Ty @hakre for indent example - I know that programmers have their own routines as to what looks "clean" an I appreciate the time you took to show me in this case - cheers

Comment: @tokenloko: I just pasted it in an editor and run the auto-formatting. my comment was just to tell that it's not a specific suggestion to do that exactly in this way.

Answer (score 0):

> so that the last menu item of the first row of page links does not print a pipe.

This is a common problem. You need to know when the last element is there or not. You can do this by caching so that you know if an element is the last element or not (compare with  [`CachingIterator::hasNext()`](http://php.net/CachingIterator.hasNext), or [`count()`](http://php.net/count) if you're working with arrays).

In your case it is perhaps most easy to create an `xpath` expression that fetches all those entries from the menu that you're interested in.

That is first for the current page and second for the user-group you have there (secure 0/1).

http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic covers how to do that.

Once done, the `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` method will give you an array you can iterate over to output your menu. You can then use a condition based on `count()` or do array-iteration and cache it to use the `CachingIterator::hasNext()` method to find out wheter you're on the last row or not.

```
$entries = $xml->xpath($query);
$entries = new CachingIterator(new ArrayIterator($entries));
foreach ($entries as $entry) 
{
    $menutItem = menu_item_create_from_xml($entry);
    menu_item_output($menutItem, $entries->hasNext());
                                 # ^^^ tell the menu output function whether or 
                                 #     not this is the last element of the menu
}
```

Comment: Got a real bad feeling I'm in over my head here - I think I need to go visit Googly docs again to research some of these suggestions - I appreciate all of you guys valuable time - thx

Comment: well, the problem with your question is that it's not narrowed down. try to isolate your problem, then I can provide better suggestions. the answer is equally broad therefore you most likely can not read much out of it.